# What is the correct connection string for sa user in appsettings.json

Tags: connection-string, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to get the correct connection string for sa user in asp.net core, appsettings.json

"DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=CakeShop;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

with

```
User Id=sa;Password=*****;
```